# Check is object exists in property

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to see if the property contains another object.

I have this:

```
{
  "prop1": "value",
  "prop2": "value",
  "prop4": "value",
  "prop5": {
      "innerprop1": "value",
      "innerprop2": "value"
  },
  "prop6": {
      "innerprop3": "value",
      "innerprop4": "value"
  }
}
```

I want to know if any of the properties has an object in it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: obj[property].Constructor === Object  does the trick

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check prop7

```js
obj = {
  "prop1": "value",
  "prop2": "value",
  "prop4": "value",
  "prop5": {
      "innerprop1": "value",
      "innerprop2": "value"
  },
  "prop6": {
      "innerprop3": "value",
      "innerprop4": "value"
  },
  "prop7": [] // Also an object!
}

for(var key in obj) {

  if(typeof obj[key] === 'object') {
    console.log(key)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
var yourObject={
  "prop1": "value",
  "prop2": "value",
  "prop4": "value",
  "prop5": {
      "innerprop1": "value",
      "innerprop2": "value"
  },
  "prop6": {
      "innerprop3": "value",
      "innerprop4": "value"
  }
}

if(typeof yourObject.prop5=='object'){
console.log("It is object")
}
```

```
if (typeof yourobject.prop5=='object'){
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with [`typeof()`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjftsOR9abVAhXBopQKHYsfAuoQFggqMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen-US%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FOperators%2Ftypeof&usg=AFQjCNHHKTIl4skD75ezgzD1s6TJcXxF8A) method and [`Object.values`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi8sfe99abVAhWKFpQKHU4aBd8QFggqMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_objects%2FObject%2Fvalues&usg=AFQjCNE5UlL1cEh99fUgeunohGICKbz8Ew)

1. `Object.values` create the array for values and [`Array.map()`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiFh6HI9abVAhWDjpQKHQ3PDKMQFggsMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FArray%2Fmap&usg=AFQjCNHaY16WQvsRJFKI1AN9YJUvUNjsCg) recreate array the with  condition  `typeof(a) == 'object'`

```js
var arr ={ "prop1": "value", "prop2": "value", "prop4":"value", "prop5": { "innerprop1": "value","innerprop2": "value" }, "prop6": { "innerprop3":"value", "innerprop4": "value" } }

//returning the keyname
console.log(Object.keys(arr).filter(a=> typeof(arr[a]) == 'object' ))

var res = Object.values(arr).map(function(a){
return typeof(a) == 'object'
})

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `typeof` function which will return `object` for objects

```
var json = '{ "prop1": "value", "prop2": "value", "prop4": "value", "prop5": { "innerprop1": "value", "innerprop2": "value" }, "prop6": { "innerprop3": "value", "innerprop4": "value" } }';
jsonObject = JSON.parse(json);
var keys = Object.keys(jsonObject);
keys.forEach(function(element){
  console.log(typeof(jsonObject[element]));

})
```